# Add and remove a class correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malleswar/F2smc/12/)

Here blue-bar appears if we mouseenter on any Span (Span1 or Span2 or Span3) and disappear after mouseleave. And when clicked on any Span (Span1 or Span2 or Span3), blue bar will stick to tha respective Span. What I want is after one Span is clicked, and we hover on another Span the blue bar must disappear on clicked Span and appear on hover Span.

For reference:
[See](http://www.multiways.com/)

here in links ( home, chi siamo, serizi , portfolio, contatti)
If 'chi siamo' link is pressed, a blue bar appears on top and when hover on another links blue bar disappears on 'chi siamo' and appears on which link is hovered. If nothing other link is clicked, blue bar reappear on 'chi siamo'. I want this without the blue horizontal scroll bar thing.

**CSS**

```
    div.demo {
        display:table;
        min-width:100%;
    }
    div.demo div {
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        width: 33%;
    }
    .under {
        width:100px;
        height:2px;
        background-color:blue;
        margin:0px auto;
        display:block;
    }
    .active {
        width:100px;
        height:2px;
        background-color:blue;
        margin:0px auto;
        display:block;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="demo">
        <div id='span1'>Span 1</div>
        <div id='span2'>Span 2</div>
        <div id='span3'>Span 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="demo">
        <div><span id='Span1'>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div><span id='Span2'>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div><span id='Span3'>&nbsp;</span></div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#span1').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span1').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span1').click(function(){
        $('#Span1').addClass('active');
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span2').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span2').click(function(){
        $('#Span2').addClass('active');
        $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });    
    $('#span3').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span3').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span3').click(function(){
        $('#Span3').addClass('active');
        $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span1').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span1').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span2').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span3').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span3').removeClass('under');
    });

});
```

Comment: Why so much JavaScript when basic CSS `:hover` can do it?

Comment: I'm just a beginner, will do that, thanks

Comment: overkill. :hover does not work well with old IEs

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id='span1' class="span-h">Span 1</div>
    <div id='span2' class="span-h">Span 2</div>
    <div id='span3' class="span-h">Span 3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <div><span id='Span1' class="span-b">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div><span id='Span2' class="span-b">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div><span id='Span3' class="span-b">&nbsp;</span></div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $fixed, $spanb = $('.span-b');
    var $spans = $('.span-h').hover(function(){
        $spanb.filter('.under').removeClass('under');
        $spanb.eq($(this).index()).addClass('under');
    }, function(){
        $spanb.eq($(this).index()).removeClass('under');
        if($fixed){
            $fixed.addClass('under');
        }
    }).click(function(){
        $fixed = $spanb.eq($(this).index()).addClass('under');
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VwD4K/)

Another variation without `$fixed` variable, instead uses a class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $spanb = $('.span-b');
    var $spanh = $('.span-h').hover(function () {
        $spanb.filter('.under').removeClass('under');
        $spanb.eq($(this).index()).addClass('under');
    }, function () {
        $spanb.eq($(this).index()).removeClass('under');
        $spanb.filter('.fixed').addClass('under');
    }).click(function () {
        $spanb.filter('.fixed').removeClass('fixed');
        $spanb.eq($(this).index()).addClass('under').addClass('fixed');
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ZWQa/)

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2smc/17/)

```
  var prev;    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#span1').mouseenter(function(){
                $('#Span1').addClass('under');
                 $(prev).removeClass('under');
                 $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span3').removeClass('active');

            });

            $('#span1').click(function(){
                prev="#Span1";
                $('#Span1').addClass('active');
                $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
            });
            $('#span2').mouseenter(function(){
               $(prev).removeClass('under');
                $('#Span2').addClass('under');
                            $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
            });

            $('#span2').click(function(){
                 prev="#Span2";
                $('#Span2').addClass('active');
                $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
            });    
            $('#span3').mouseenter(function(){
                $(prev).removeClass('under');
                $('#Span3').addClass('under');
                            $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
            });

            $('#span3').click(function(){
                prev="#Span3";
                $('#Span3').addClass('active');
                $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
                $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
            });
            $('#span1').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#Span1').removeClass('under');
                 $(prev).addClass('under');
            });
            $('#span2').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#Span2').removeClass('under');
                $(prev).addClass('under');
            });
            $('#span3').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#Span3').removeClass('under');
                $(prev).addClass('under');
            });

        });
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work.once you click on one link, and hover on any other links and didn't click any, the previous clicked one doesn't get highlighted

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the CSS classes during the click event of the spans. Check this fiddle.Its working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#span1').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span1').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span1').click(function(){
        $('#Span1').addClass('active');
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span2').addClass('under');
        $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span2').click(function(){
        $('#Span2').addClass('active');
        $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });    
    $('#span3').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span3').addClass('under');
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span3').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span3').click(function(){
        $('#Span3').addClass('active');
        $('#Span1').removeClass('active');
        $('#Span2').removeClass('active');
    });
    $('#span1').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span1').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span2').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span3').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span3').removeClass('under');
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JWSxQ/

Cheers!!!

Comment: No, this doesn't work.once you click on one link, and hover on any other links and didn't click any, the previous clicked one doesn't get highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `active` dom element in memory and toggle it on mouseEnter and mouseLeave:

```
function showUnder(){
        under.addClass('active');
    }
    function hideUnder(){
        under = $('.active');
        under.removeClass('active');
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F2smc/27/)

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/F2smc/25/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').hover(function(){
        $(".link").each(function(){
            $('.link').removeClass('under');
        }); 
        $(this).addClass('under');
    });
    $('.link').click(function(){
        $(".link").each(function(){
            $('.link').removeClass('active');
        }); 
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('under');       
    });
  $('.link').mouseout(function() {
      var cnt =0;
      $(".under").each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('under');
            cnt++;
       });
      if(cnt==1) {
          $(".active").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('under');
          });   
      }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when i do this type of coding i always define a variable `selected`.

which contains the selected id/index...

so if i click span1 selected contains 'span1'.

doing so i can have a function like this:

```
var selected=false;
function select(e){
 if(selected){
  document.getElementById(selected).classList.remove('active');
 }
 e.target.classList.add('active');
 selected=e.target.id;
}
```

and the hover thing is done by simple css.

i wrote it in normal javascript..
this is the actual correct way to add and remove classes

```
element.classList.add();
element.classList.remove();
element.classList.toggle();
```

but you can easely convert it to jQuery if you want and as this way is supported only by modern browsers.webkit+css3

here is the DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/f7epx/

and here is the full code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    div.demo{
        display:table;
        min-width:100%;
    }
    div.demo>div {
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        width: 33%;
    }
    div.demo>div:hover>div>div{
        width:50%;
        height:2px;
        background-color:grey;
        margin:0px auto;
        display:block;
    }
    div.demo>div.active>div>div{
        width:50%;
        height:2px;
        background-color:blue;
        margin:0px auto;
        display:block;
    }
    div.demo>div>div>div{
        width:0%;
        height:2px;
        background-color:grey;
        margin:0px auto;
        display:block;
        -webkit-transition:all 700ms ease;
        -moz-transition:all 700ms ease;
        -ms-transition:all 700ms ease;
    }
</style>
<script>
var selected=false;
function select(e){
 if(selected){
  document.getElementById(selected).classList.remove('active');
 }
 document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.add('active');
 selected=e.target.id;
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('click',select,false);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="x" class="demo">
  <div id="span1">Uno<div><div></div></div></div>
  <div id="span2">Due<div><div></div></div></div>
  <div id="span3">Tre<div><div></div></div></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you have any questions just ask